# Bongard Problem 4: Circles

Tags: pattern, bongard

Find the rule that is all correct on the left side, but not on the right side. If you don't know about bongard problems you can [click here](http://www.foundalis.com/res/diss_research.html).

[image: bongard4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ones on the left

> Have an odd number of circles completely contained inside of other circles. Clockwise from top left: 1,1,3,5,5,3.

The ones on the right

> Have an even number of circles completely contained inside of other circles. Clockwise from top left: 0,2,2,2,2,2.

Comment: Good spot, but there is a confusion on the right side, bottom right, the only diagram where *gur pbagnvarq pvepyrf vagrefrpg*.

Comment: There’s no confusion there — on the right side, exactly two circles are completely contained inside the larger circle. The intersection is not a circle itself, and a circle intersecting with another is not fully contained inside the other circle.

Comment: I am talking about bottom right. Which are you replying about?

Comment: The bottom right corner of the right side. How many circles would you count as fully contained? @WeatherVane

Comment: The same but I don't get your comment about that area: "a circle intersecting with another is not fully contained inside the other circle". They are both fully contained. My point is that they intersect, unlike any other contained circle.

Comment: But that doesn’t matter, is what I’m saying. Whether they intersect or not, they are two fully contained circles and so belong on the right. @WeatherVane anything else seems to me to be additional design features which aren’t part of the overarching rule.